# Describe the set of all matrices C such that $C^{-1}AC = A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Given a square matrix A, can we find all invertible matrices C such that $A = C^{-1}AC$ ? In other words, can we find a set of all bases such that the matrix of an endomorphism $f$ in those bases is $A$?

The word "find" above should be interpreted as "find a good description/ way of enumeration of the set of such matrices". I believe that one may not be able to do so for all matrices but some of special kinds (such as diagonalizable ones). Anyway I just ask for sure/ to get some insights about this.

Comment: That is $AC=CA$.

Comment: To find an "enumeration" seems quite optimistic.

Answer (score 3):

$$
A = C^{-1}AC
$$
implies
$$
CA=AC
$$
So you are looking for invertible matrix $C$ such commute with $A$. Look at wiki page on [commuting matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices).

Or look as this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478849/when-will-ab-ba).

Comment: *invertible matrix C.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, set of all such $C$ always contains the identity matrix.  For diagonalizable ones, any scalar multiple of the diagonalizing matrix also belongs to set of $C$.