# Simultaneous diagonalizability and matrix polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that two [matrices commute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices) ($AB = BA$) if [they are simultaneously diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478849/when-will-ab-ba).

I also know that they commute if [B is a polynomial of A](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/92482/50804) ( $B = \sum_{k=0}^na_kA^{k+1}$).

---

What I do not know is whether these two statements mean the same thing (and if so how can it be proved).

Comment: No. They don't mean the same thing. The second statement is essentially trivial. Whereas, the first statement is stating something more general.

Comment: @JackyChong Thank you. Am I right with thinking that 2) is a subset of 1)? Also does this mean that if B is a polynomial of A, then A and B are simultaneously diagonalizable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out, there are many simultaneously diagonalizable matrices such that neither is a polynomial of the other. One example that comes to mind is
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 &1 & 0  \\0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix},\quad \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 &2 & 0  \\0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}
$$
since no polynomial in $A$ can make the topmost two diagonal entries unequal, and no polynomial in $B$ can make the bottommost two diagonal entries unequal.

However, if one matrix is a polynomial of the other, say
$$
B = a_nA^n + \cdots + a_1A + a_0I
$$
and $A$ is diagonalisable (say $A = PDP^{-1}$, with $D$ diagonal), then
$$
B = a_n(PDP^{-1})^n + \cdots + a_1PDP^{-1} + a_0I \\
 = a_nPD^nP^{-1} + \cdots + a_1PDP^{-1} + a_0PIP^{-1}\\
= P(a_nD^n + \cdots + a_1D + a_0I)P^{-1} = PEP^{-1}
$$
where $E = a_nD^n + \cdots + a_1D + a_0I$ is diagonal. So $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalisable.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider that the a [scalar matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix#Scalar_matrix) commutes with all matrices (of the same dimension), but a polynomial function of a scalar matrix gives a scalar matrix.

And consider that two commuting matrices are  [simultaneously triangularizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices#Characterization_in_terms_of_eigenvectors) and are simultaneouly diagonalizable if they are also diagonalizable.