# In which cases does $(A \cdot B)^{-1} = A^{-1} \cdot B^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

What are the restrictions on $A$ and/or $B$ for which the following holds? (in addition to the requirements that A and B should be invertible): 
$$
(A\cdot B)^{-1} = A^{-1}\cdot B^{-1}
$$

Given that for all square invertible matrices: 
$$
(A\cdot B)^{-1} = B^{-1}\cdot A^{-1}
$$
Thanks!

Comment: $A^{-1} = B^{-1}$

Comment: @quester, that can be true for any two invertible matrices that commute.

Answer (score 6):

Because of the two identities you wrote, what we want is essentially: 
$$ A^{-1} B^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1} $$

We already assumed that A and B are invertible, thus $ \det(A) \neq 0 $ and $ \det(B) \neq 0 $, so $A^{-1} B^{-1}$ should also be invertible, because $\det(A^{-1} B^{-1}) = \det(A^{-1}) \det(B^{-1}) = \det(A)^{-1} \det(B)^{-1} \neq 0 $

Then, if we can invert both the left and the right hand side of the identity above:

$$ (A^{-1} B^{-1})^{-1} = (B^{-1} A^{-1})^{-1}  \iff $$
$$ (B^{-1})^{-1} (A^{-1})^{-1} = (A^{-1})^{-1} (B^{-1})^{-1} \iff $$
$$ B A = A B $$

So if the two matrices commute when multiplied (which is generally not true for arbitrary matrices), then it also holds that $(AB)^{-1} = A^{-1} B^{-1}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: To make this answer complete, see here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478849/when-will-ab-ba